# Where is the pdf of the US Census data stored that contains all the codes?

Tags: census

I'm working with US census data and I can't locate the documentation that explains all of the codes (e.g. P01001 etc) that is used to describe the attribute tables in the shapefiles.

I haven't been able to find it on the [www.census.gov](http://www.census.gov/main/www/cen2000.html) site and it's tricky to search for if you forget the exact name (which I have!).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [Census Summary Files](http://factfinder.census.gov/servlet/DatasetMainPageServlet). Search [SF1](http://www.census.gov/prod/cen2000/doc/sf1.pdf) for P01001 and you'll get a few hits.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help!